# Gtk/python and portability

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygtk

How do programmers write portable UI code that works on multiple distributions? I am considering desktop distributions and not specialized/embedded distributions. For writing UI applications, you have to assume certain things will be available on the platform either as standard or by means of added dependencies. Is there a "minimum" UI/widget standard that Linux distributions own?

How does Gnome vs KDE distributions come into picture when you are writing the code?

I have a python script that uses Gtk and Webkit. Following are imports that my script uses.

```
import os
import threading
from gi.repository import WebKit 
from gi.repository import Gtk 
from gi.repository import GLib, GObject
```

What will be the best source to find out on which distributions my code will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much stuff you have to consider for writing a cross-distribution UI.
Actually the only incompatibility issue that I can remember is:

Tray Icon or Notification Area or App Indicator (so called in Ubuntu)
For example standard tray icon (created by `gtk.StatusIcon` does not work in Ubuntu's Unity by default
You better use `appindicator.Indicator` if appindicator module was found, otherwise just use classic `StatusIcon`

And if you care too much about the style/theme of your program, you may have issues on other environments like KDE
Unless you use suitable Theme Engines to act like a bridge, take a look at:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_Look_for_Qt_and_GTK_Applications

For finding out about the distribution / OS, I have written such a function:

```
def getOsFullDesc():
    name = ''
    if os.path.isfile('/etc/lsb-release'):
        lines = open('/etc/lsb-release').read().split('\n')
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION='):
                name = line.split('=')[1]
                if name[0]=='"' and name[-1]=='"':
                    return name[1:-1]
    if os.path.isfile('/suse/etc/SuSE-release'):
        return open('/suse/etc/SuSE-release').read().split('\n')[0]
    try:
        import platform
        return ' '.join(platform.dist()).strip().title()
        #return platform.platform().replace('-', ' ')
    except ImportError:
        pass
    if os.name=='posix':
        osType = os.getenv('OSTYPE')
        if osType!='':
            return osType
    ## sys.platform == 'linux2'
    return os.name
```

Comment: Good answer. Addresses the points that were implicit in the question but not explicitly asked.

Answer (score 0):

Python is basically a glue language - it doesn't do much on its own but depends on various libraries like pygtk, tkinter, etc. or even your custom C/C++ modules. to do its stuff. So logically, all you need are the particular dependencies for your said libraries: PyGTK & WebKit to be installed on your target machine.

Once you have them installed on a Windows or even a MAC, along with Python, python will happily execute this code since all it does is glues!!

Comment: One reason for why python works this way is that it is interpreted and not compiled. While this mode is good for ease of development and cross-platform compatibility, it is not that good for performance. Thus, you write just the initial skeleton or glue code in python, and leave performance sensitive or OS-dependent code to libraries and custom modules.